# Python: match lists in two lists of lists

Tags: python, join, list

I have two lists of lists. The first is composed of lists formatted as follows:

```
listInA = [id, a1, a2, a3]
```

The second is composed of lists formatted similarly, with the id first:

```
listInB = [id, b1, b2, b3]
```

Neither list is sorted, and they are not of equal lengths.  What is the best way to make a list of lists, with each list of the format:

```
listInC = [id, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3]
```

where the id's are matched between both lists? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dictionary using dict comprehension from the second list of lists from ID to list. Then, create your new list using list comprehension, appending the list based on IDs.

```
listA = [
    [1, 'a', 'b', 'c'],
    [2, 'd', 'e', 'f'],
]
listB = [
    [2, 'u', 'v', 'w'],
    [1, 'x', 'y', 'z'],
]

b_map = {b[0]: b for b in listB}
print([a + b_map[a[0]][1:] for a in listA])
```

**Output:**

```
[
    [1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
    [2, 'd', 'e', 'f', 'u', 'v', 'w']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the lists are not sorted and are not of equal length increases the difficulty of coming up with an efficient solution to the problem. However, a quick and dirty solution that would work in the end is definitely still feasible.

The ID seems to be first in both lists. Since this is the case, then for each list `a` in `A`, we can get the first element of `a` and check the lists `b` in `B`. If the first elements match, then we can create a list including the remaining elements of `a` and `b` and append that to `C`. In short...

```
def foo(A, B):
   C = []
   for a in A:
      aID = a[0]
      for b in B:
         if aID == b[0]:
            c = [aID, a[1], a[2], a[3], b[1], b[2], b[3]]
            C.append(c)
   return C
```

When dealing with large list sizes for `A` and `B`, the efficiency of this solution would drop abysmally, but it should work for reasonably-sized lists.